# Data inserted into the database but has empty values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form that upon successful completion, it should get inserted into the data base, however, this is not what happens, what happens is that i see in the table of the database that the "id" is incremented by 1, but the other columns in the table are empty, so the connection to the data base is not the issue, could use some help, thank you everyone. below is the php code for my form, as well the the inserting code.

```html
<?php


// define variables and set to empty values
$staffErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $problemErr = $descriptionErr= "";
$staffname = $email = $subject = $problem_type = $description = "";


// staff name validation:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["staff_name"])) {
    $staffErr = "Staff Name is required";
} else {
    $staffname = test_input($_POST["staff_name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$staffname)) {
    $staffErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }    
}


if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Please enter a valid email.";
    }
}


// subject validation:

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = "Subject is required";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
        // check if subject only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$subject)) {
        $subjectErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
    



// problem type validation:

if (empty($_POST["problem_type"])) {
    $problemErr = "Problem type is required";
} else {
    $problem_type = test_input($_POST["problem_type"]);
}

// description validation:

if (empty($_POST["description"])) {
    $descriptionErr = "A Description is required";
} else {
    $description = test_input($_POST["description"]);
}


}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($staffErr == "" && $emailErr == "" &&$subjectErr == "" &&$problemErr == "" &&$descriptionErr == "") {
    header("Location:insert_logs.php");
            exit(); 
            
             } 
     else {
                header("Location:log-it-reports.php");
            exit(); 
}
     }
?>



    <div class= "content">
       
       <div class="form1">
        <form  method="POST" onsubmit=" return formSubmit() " >
          <div class="error1" id= "errorMsg">* Required Fields</div>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg1">*<?php echo $staffErr; ?></div>
          <div>
          <label for="staff_name"><b>Staff Name:</b></label> 
          <input  class="field" id="staff_name" name="staff_name" onclick=" return staffValidation()" onchange=" return staffValidation()" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Staff Name"  > 
          </div><br>

          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg2">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
          <div>
          <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label> 
          <input class="field" id="email1" name="email" onclick=" return emailValidation()" onchange=" return emailValidation()" type="email" placeholder="staff@wearview.com">  
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg3">*<?php echo $subjectErr;?></div>
          <div>
          <label for="subject"><b>Subject:</b></label> 
          <input  class="field" name="subject" id="subject1" onclick=" return subjectValidation()" onchange=" return subjectValidation()" type="text" placeholder="Subject Title"  > 
          </div><br>

          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg4">*<?php echo $problemErr;?></div>
          <div>
            <select onclick=" return problemValidation()" onchange=" return problemValidation()" class="field4" name="problem_type" id="problemtypes">
                <option value="">Problem Type</option>
                <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Software&Hardware">Software & Hardware</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg5">*<?php echo $descriptionErr;?></div>
          <div>
          <textarea class="field2" id="description1" name="description" onclick=" return descriptionValidation()" onchange=" return descriptionValidation()" placeholder="Description goes here" name="descript" rows="15" cols="90"></textarea>
          </div>          
          
          <div>
            <button class="field3" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="notify" name="notify" value="">
            <label for="notify">Inform me by email when issue is resolved.</label> 
        </div>
        </form>
       
    </div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inserting IT reports into the database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="update.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
        //inserting inputs to the data base
        //database connection variables for the database on your web server
        $servername = "localhost"; 
        $username = "*******";
        $password = "*******";
        $database = "attack_titan"; 
        
        //saving all of the user's POST values from the the form submission to local variables
        $staffname = $_POST['staffname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subjects'];
        $problem_type = $_POST['problem_type'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        


       
        //we start a try and catch block to attempt to connect to our database and run the query. If it fails, we see the error/exception generated by the catch
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password); //building a new PDO connection object
           
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // set the PDO error mode to exception

             // prepare sql and bind parameters

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO it_reports (staff_name, email, subjects, problem_type, descriptions)
            VALUES ('$staffname', '$email', '$subject', '$problem_type', '$description')");
            $stmt->bindParam(':staffname', $staffname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
            $stmt->bindParam(':problem_type', $problem_Type);
            $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);

            
            // use execute() to run the query
            $stmt->execute();
            
            echo "<p class = 'inserted' >Your report has been submitted successfully</p><br>"  ,  '<a class = "button" href="log-it-reports.php">Click to go back to the previous page</a>';
            // If successful we will see this
            // you could then check PHPMyAdmin to see if the record was inserted
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Error" . $e->getMessage(); //If we are not successful we will see an error
            }
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your insert statement.
Try to change:

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO it_reports (staff_name, email, subjects, problem_type, descriptions) VALUES ('$staffname', '$email', '$subject', '$problem_type', '$description')");`

with

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO it_reports (staff_name, email, subjects, problem_type, descriptions) VALUES (:staffname, :email, :subject, :problem_type, :description)");`

So, the bindValue statement can works